# How to maintain mail conversion (reply / forward / reply to all like gmail) of email using Python pop/imap lib?

Tags: python, imap, pop3, imaplib, poplib

I've develop webmail client for any mail server.
I want to implement message conversion for it — for example same emails fwd/reply/reply2all should be shown together like gmail does...

My question is: what's the key to find those emails which are either reply/fwd or related to the original mail....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `In-Reply-To` header of the child should have the value of the `Message-Id` header of the parent(s).

Answer (score 3):

Google just seems to chain messages based on the subject line (so does Apple Mail by the way.)

Comment: Which is why you should never change the subject line unless you want to create a different conversation.